# Responsive triangle div

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a **responsive triangle div** which will sit at the top of the page as a header.

I was able to achieve that with the following  code:

```css
div{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 400px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The problem is that I want this triangle to be **responsive to the width of the page** and change proportionally in height as well.

I tried setting width and height to percent based, however that produced a really small triangle which you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltbzkq0e/1/

How to make the borders work with percent without having to use webkits?  Is that possible, if not how do I achieve this effect with webkits?

EDIT:

I would also like to fit content in this div.  At the moment the only way I can think of is to use absolute positioning and set height to -20px, etc...  Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: This looks like a job for javascript to me.

Comment: Won't be much use as a 'header' since it can't hold content.

Comment: I've updated my question as I've realized the limitations of using borders and transformations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transform-rotate` and a pseudo element to create a **responsive triangle**. This technique is detailed here : [CSS triangles with transform rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808936/1811992).

For your specific case it could look like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hnc597cv/)**

```css
.tr{
    padding-bottom:30%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.tr:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:120%; height:100%;
    background-color : #0079C6;
    
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 100%;
    transform-origin:0 100%;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-17deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-17deg);
    transform: rotate(-17deg);
}
.content{
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="tr">
    <div class="content"> ... CONTENT HERE ...</div>
</div>
```

If you need IE8 support, you will need to use a JS fallback. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936655/how-to-create-an-triangle-shape-fixed-height-width-100-with-background-using/26698502#26698502) describes a way to achieve it.

Comment: How come the width of the triangle doesn't reach the end of the page and yet you have the width set at 120%.  What would I have to do for it to hit corner to corner, is it just a matter of playing with % or different angle rotations as well?

Comment: you can play with the rotation angle and the `padding-bottom` on .tr to tweak it as desired.

Comment: @Bagzli like this (tweaked bottom padding) http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hnc597cv/2/

Answer (score 3):

if you don't care about IE8 and recent Android support — and since you need to have border-width proportional to the page size — you [can use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) viewport-based (`vw` and `vh`) units

e.g.

```
border-width: 100vw 100vh 0 0;
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swbfqemr/

Comment: I think you have vw and vh swapped.  Never the less it worked for what I was initially asking.  Now that I've tried to take this a step further I've encountered another problem.  I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Didn't you mean it the other way arounde, i.e. `border-width: 100vh 100vw 0 0;`.