# CSS triangle border-width does not work with percentage value relative to the parent

Tags: css, css-shapes

I made a right-angled triangle with this CSS code:

```css
height: 0;
border-width: 0 0 100px 1000px;
border-color: transparent red red transparent;
border-style: solid;
```

The problem is, I cant use `%` instead of `px`.

I want to make right-angled triangle width `100%` but it totally does not work. I know I can add `width:100%;` but the triangle won't look good and I will have to adjust the diagonal line with `px`. that is not handy. because if I make the window smaller, the triangle wont scale.

Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`border-width`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#border-width) cannot have a percentage value. The permitted values are:

> `<line-width>` = `<length>` | thin | medium | thick

Where [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) is a [`<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number) followed by length units: `px, em, rem, ...`.

---

That being said, one possible CSS option is to use [viewport relative unit `vw`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths) to set the width of the border according to the width of the viewport.

In that case, you just need to calculate the width of the parent element relative to the width of the viewport. If the parent fill the entire horizontal space, go with `100vw`; If it fills the half of viewport: `50vw` and so on.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

div {
  height:0;
  border-width:0 0 100px 100vw;
  border-color:transparent red red transparent;
  border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

It's worth mentioning that `vw` viewport percentage length [is supported in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Answer (score 0):

Border can't be in percents, see the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width).

Try to see my older question, [How to create an triangle shape (fixed height, width=100%) with background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936655/how-to-create-an-triangle-shape-fixed-height-width-100-with-background-using), it can helps you.